# getting error while creating nginx image with packer in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, packer

Build 'amazon-ebs' errored after 2 seconds 246 milliseconds: error validating regions: AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
status code: 401, request id: 8265d7d2-3360-4eeb-a801-c6d28933a93c

==> Wait completed after 2 seconds 246 milliseconds

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> amazon-ebs: error validating regions: AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
status code: 401, request id: 8265d7d2-3360-4eeb-a801-c6d28933a93c

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure the Amazon Time Sync Service on your instance:

```
sudo yum erase ntp*
sudo yum -y install chrony
sudo service chrony start
```

Comment: i just added only builders and did not add any provisioners  just i am trying to create only basic image